# Problema ao instalar boostrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

Estou tentando instalar o Bootstrap usando NodeJS pelo terminal e é exibido o seguinte erro:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for
jquery@next npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your
dependencies are requesting npm ERR! notarget a package version that
doesn't exist.
 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
C:\Users\Thiag\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-12T17_43_37_258Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\Thiag\Documents\angular2\angular-cli-libs>
```

*O que devo fazer para contornar esta falha?*

<sub>**grato**</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Tente

```
npm install bootstrap
```

qual comando utilizou?